# Get coordinates of displayed rectangle

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, render

I'm trying to create a game for Android device and I have a small question about the rendering of the scene. Effectively I want to draw a square of a precise size but I'm not pretty sure about the way I can get the coordinates of the border of the screen in openGL dimension. My application is set in landscape mode, so computation looks easier.

I have drawn a square with a border size of 2 and I have the impression that the square takes all the height of the screen. Since I know the resolution of my screen which is equal to 1920*1080, I can compute the width of my scene. Then, by drawing several squares I found the coordinates of on corner.

This way of computing the coordinates are a bit weird and I'm not pretty sure that the computation will always lead to a good answer. Is there a nicer way and obviously a better way to compute those coordinates ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: What kind of projection are you using? Orthogonal? Is it a 2D game?

Comment: The size of your scene is usually defined by you. By default you are having a coordinate system where left = -1, right = 1, top = 1, bottom = -1. After that there are matrix operations that define your scene and most common keywords you need to search for are "ortho" and "frustum". Both include border parameters (left, right, top, bottom) and those define your scene size. Though frustum depends on the Z coordinate and the border parameters are defined at Z = near.

Comment: @samgak : Yes it is a 2D game but I think I used the 3D "mode" since I call Matrix.setLookAtM(). I began to learn OpenGL some weeks ago and I know that the full version allows you to switch to "resolution" coordinates. By using the orthogonal projection, is it the same ?

Comment: @MaticOblak : I'm currently using the Matrix.setLookAtM projection since I started from the Android Training example. Do I have to use Matrix.orthoM instead ?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to achieve. Look at does not change your scene size though. There must be something else or you must be defaulting to the coordinate system explained above though I doubt it. At some point you need to take your screen (view) ration or the screen size. Try and find it.

Comment: I'm not pretty sure to understand what you mean but at one point, I do need to set the ratio so that dimensions are kept (I mean a square is a square and not a rectangle). I try to implement a 2D game but I want to begin step by step and here is the first thing I would like to implement. I think you are right and I'm not pretty sure that there is a nice way to compute this. I will have a look the find an answer or another way to do this.